# How can I write good questions?

Tags: discussion

Please don't direct me to the Help Page.  I need guidance that the Help Page doesn't give.

I am a native English speaker, and know only basic grammar. I know when something sounds right, I know when it sounds wrong, and I know when it sounds right even though technically it is wrong. I cannot explain grammar beyond basic grammar.

I am discouraged by some of the grammar questions asked here, and I mean discouraged by the **good** questions, because they seem like Greek to me. It seems like learning advanced grammar is like studying anatomy, physiology and biochemistry in order to learn how to walk.

I don't know enough grammar to write a decent grammar question.  And I suspect the Catch 22 is that if I did study grammar, I would know how to research the answers to almost anything that occurred to me.  Or would it take years of study to get to that point?

As for writing questions about words or idioms or sayings, almost everything along those lines can be found in a quick Google search.  Thus, I mostly answer (16 Questions vs 392 Answers), and answering is becoming less satisfying.  When I can get 89 net upvotes for seethe ([Word to describe to sit in quiet anger](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/400036/word-to-describe-to-sit-in-quiet-anger/400042#400042)), it is too easy.  **I'm not complaining** about 89 upvotes -- far from it -- but it is excessive and excess cloys. (But never hesitate to upvote me, please! :))

So, the question: **what can I do, short of going to grad school, to write good questions and contribute to the question side of ELU?**

Comment: I am not sure what this post is about. You are complaining  about poor questions asked by ESL students and about too many upvotes for an answer that came easy to your mind. Basically any questions about the English language that shows  research and personal effort to find an answer is a "good one". Wether  it is an interesting one is a different matter.

Comment: I'll try to make it clearer this evening.  You completely misinterpreted the Q, for which I take the blame, totally.  I am asking how I, a native English speaker can write good questions, even though I don't know the technicalities of grammar.  I am not complaining about anything.  Some ESL users write questions about English grammar which are Greek to me; I admire them.  (Some write bad questions, this Q is not about that at all.)  I explicitly said that I am not complaining about 89 upvotes, just that it seems excessive, and excess is cloying.  Does this clarify at all?   Feedback helps.

Comment: I think the issue here is  what you mean by "good". On topic questions are all 'good" by definition. They may be more or less elaborated and may attract users' attention  according to the topic they refer to (grammar, orthography, pronounciation, meaning in context, etymology etc.). You have asked 16 questions so far, and at a quick glance they all appear "good" by the site standards.

Comment: Related: [How can I rekindle interest in an old question?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10479/how-can-i-rekindle-interest-in-an-old-question)

Comment: That's a *good question*! To me, the starting point is to stumble upon some point of interest that sparks your curiosity. Now, *that* is considerably harder to manufacture. Nevertheless, if something is of interest to you (and on-topic here), it's probably of interest to the wider EL&U community as well - regardless of how non-technically the question is phrased, so long as it conveys your intent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Just be yourself**. You're also keen to learn, which is great. Admit you don't know the terminology, that technical answers should be pared down so you don't need to be a linguist in order to understand, and if the question is interesting, it won't matter if grammar terms are thin on the ground. Eventually, you'll keep hearing the same terms used again and again and they will stick.

**Include your research**, or your gut feelings as a native speaker, show you have spent time thinking it through. Be cheerful. Be hopeful, but don't be upset if your question doesn't receive a standing ovation. It probably won't.

Here's but one example of a non-expert asking a grammar question.

[What's wrong with "I'll open you the door"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90530/whats-wrong-with-ill-open-you-the-door)

and here's another question asked by an EFL teacher but it is simple to understand, hopefully, you already know what an *adjective*, *noun*, *verb*, and *infinitive phrase* is.

[Why does "I was happy to do my homework" work, but "I was tired to do my homework" doesn't?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/363763/why-does-i-was-happy-to-do-my-homework-work-but-i-was-tired-to-do-my-homewor)

Always a good idea to ask users to supply examples, and/or links in their answers.

Comment: +1 Are you a native English speaker? And are you a teacher as well? The "tired to do homework" answer you gave is neat! :) +1 to that as well.

Comment: "Not really" to both your questions. I am here to improve my English and master the more complex grammar.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Er, but I thought the answers to both those questions was "yeah, pretty much"!

Answer (score -2):

(This grew too long for a comment, and I don’t wish to encourage comments over posts.)

The simple answer is to follow the lead of [our most Socratic of askers](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/161/socratic). Look at the questions posed by the holders of that gold badge, and go thou and do likewise.

The OP notices that poor questions draw poor answers, and that both are highly upvoted. If you want to write a question that everybody answers and upvotes, that’s a very different thing from asking how to write well-written and well-researched questions covering a previously unexplored matter of English that contribute to our growing library of expert answers. Compare Yoichi Oichi’s questions with the single-word-gimmes, for example.

[The one the OP drew attention to](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/400036/word-to-describe-to-sit-in-quiet-anger/400042#400042) is a writing request. I personally believe that such questions should be closed and their copypasta answers deleted. They add nothing to our library of expert answers. As you observe, they can be trivially used for reputation mills, and there have been instances of fraud on the site related to this scam.

I am hardy alone in my opinion that these questions should be disallowed by revised site rules. [We’ve talked about this since time immemorial](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity?cb=1). Constantly.

But nobody wants to pull the trigger on these requests (not questions, requests) for this or that “catchy, fun word that means X sprinkled with Y while gazing into the Z”. Supposedly they’re too “fun” to kill off.

Stack Overflow *used* to have joke questions and write-my-code-for-me questions. They were incredibly popular. It took serious effort and collective community will, but these terrible, pointless questions were finally given the kiss of everlasting death.

They’re offtopic `gimme-the-codez` demands, and nowhere else on the network are such questions tolerated. We should expect no less of ourselves regarding these write-my-sentence-for-me requests.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question? Does it?

Comment: Not sure OP is complaining about SWRs questions in their post.

Comment: @Josh She's noticing that poor questions draw poor answers, and that both are highly upvoted. If you want to write a question that everybody answers and upvotes, that's a very different thing from asking how to write well-written and well-researched questions covering a previously unexplored matter of English that contribute to our growing library of expert answers.

Comment: How do you know @ab2 is a "he"? :)

Comment: The same is valid for the poor grammar question OP is complaining  about. A poor question is poor because it is off-topic for one or more  reasons as stated by the site rules. A SWRs question is not poor by definition.

Comment: @Josh If for each well-written SWR you can find on the site, I can find a hundred poorly written ones, would that convince you that these are a problem?

Comment: Poorly written SRWs questions don't make SWRs questions poor. It is a different issue. Any poorly written question (whatever the topic) is just a poorly written question.

Comment: @Josh No matter what the ratio of bad to good ones should happen to be? If a question type draws several orders of magnitude more bad questions than good ones, it should be banned. This is what the Stack Exchange network has learned through experience.

Comment: This just sounds like a rant in the guise of an answer. I don't see how any helpful advice (except "don't engage in behaviors I hate") can be drawn from this answer.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I suggested that one look at the questions posed by the holders of the Gold Socratic badge for models of good questions. Is that not an answer?

Comment: No matter what the ratio of bad to good ones should happen to be.

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Josh Then we must differ in that: I believe the ratio is critical.

Comment: +1 for practical advice.  (1) Although I can't read 1,600 questions, I can read two or three questions per Socratic Badge asker.  (2)  Mari-Lou has correctly figured out that I am not a "he".

Comment: Ooh, not fair. You changed the "he" into a "she", that's called cheating from where I come from. :) :) [*Imagine me peering from behind my reading spectacles and tutting while trying to suppress a grin.*] I wonder if there is a single word that describes that facial response...?

Comment: @Mari-LouA -       A SWR for that facial expression? Don't dare ask!!!!

Comment: Mr. Tchrist, I doubt you realize what you are proposing here because it is so incongruent. Yoichi Oishi's clearly our most socratic user, as I am sure you are well aware, but that is evidence that the request questions should be kept categorically because most of his questions are [tag:translation] questions if I recall correctly, which aside from being a very well received category are just another variety of request as far as the tagging policies are concerned. Unless you can explain more, it seems to me that the difference is not in the nature of the question, but how well they are asked.