# Where can I find the rules of the English SE?

Tags: support

It's been a long time since I was last active on SE in general. Now, in the last weeks I've been super pensive about the role of language in my life, especially the ones I learned as a grown up, in particular, English.

I've been having lots of questions in my head, but I want to re-read the rules before I can ask some of the, because I'm not sure they belong in SE or if they do, how I frame them so as to get the most productive outcomes.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked over the  [help]?

Comment: This meta discussion may be helpful as well [How can I write good questions?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10621/how-can-i-write-good-questions). If you have specific areas of concern the Help Center doesn’t address, searching this meta for relevant discussions is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

While the sources suggested by ColleenV, in the comments, are helpful, there is probably no substitute for spending some time browsing around the site and picking up its culture, which can never be fully captured by explicit rules.

Comment: That is, acculturation by osmosis!

Comment: ...or maybe  _assimilation_.